# Set the color of a BorderBrush with a trigger

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, triggers

I am having some difficulty getting the syntax worked out correctly in a `ControlTemplate`. Here's is the basics of it:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type foo:bar">
    <Border Name="Bd">  
        <Border.BorderBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource DefaultBorderBrushLightBrush}" />
        </Border.BorderBrush>
    </Border>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                    TargetName="Bd"
                    Value="{DynamicResource PressedBorderDarkColor}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate
```

This yields the error msg

> Cannot resolve the Template Property 'Color)'. Verify that the owning type is the Style's TargetType, or use Class.Property syntax to specify the property.

That seems clear enough - I'm not correctly specifying the target property. I've tried it a couple of different ways. Specifically, I've tried

```
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd">
    <Setter.Value>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource PressedBorderDarkColor}" />
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

... and this does build and, I suppose, gives me what I was looking for.

Still, why can't I set the brush color? How would I specify it?

More broadly, where can I learn more about this "Class.Property syntax"? I read through MSDN's [XAML Syntax In Detail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788723%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#properties_of_object_elements) but if it's covered there I fear I overlooked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that when the Style/ControlTemplate set `TargetType`, for example - `Border`, is a property that is indicated in:

```
<Style x:Key="TestStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
```

automatically converted to:

```
<Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
```

*`Class.Property`* syntax used when clearly in the Style is not specified `TargetType`:

```
<Style x:Key="TestStyle">
    <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
```

In styles can be followed both ways, design type like:

```
(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)
```

commonly used in `Storyboard's`.

Comment: I'm lead to believe in this case there's a converter in the background that converts strings to brushes. Since the resource I'm referencing is a color, not a brush or a string, this syntax won't work for me.

So ... Is the Class.Property syntax only valid inside storyboards? Why doesn't it work here?

Comment: @mcwyrm: `Class.Property` is valid everywhere, in Styles, in Storyboards. The `TargetProperty` property of Storyboard supports complex syntax (`(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)`) that enables you to target properties of other properties. For a detailed description of the different ways to target properties, see [`Storyboards`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the brush color simply because it's not a property of the target Border object `Bd`, that target object has the property `BorderBrush` instead, the color however is a property of the object SolidColorBrush which is affected to the BorderBrush property. the syntax (Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color) is used for example when you have to specify the attached property `TargetProperty` of a StoryBoard for example in animations :

```
<VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                      (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                         Value="{StaticResource ControlMouseOverColor}" />
                  </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
```

Comment: The target object is not foo:bar; the target object is the object named "Bd" which is of type `Border`. Granted it doesn't have a `Color` property either but if you look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you'll see borders' colors set left and right (albeit w/ animations, not triggers).

Comment: @mcwyrm : I understand, and just as you said Color is not a property of the object Border, and in the case where Color is used as you said lately, it's just because it's a property of the objects they are related to such as `GradientStop`, I'll update my answer